# Creating a dynamically flexible division-tag within the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My Goal:** I want to create an HTML division that is styled to be, say, 35px from each edge of the browsers window. Also, I want this division-tag to keep that 35px space between itself and the browsers edge even if the user is zooming-in and zooming-out in their browser, and if the browser is maximized and the actual monitor is either a full screen or wide screen display.

**Visually:** A rectangular shape that dynamically adjusts its dimensions as the browsers dimensions change, but always maintains a fixed space between the rectangular shapes edge and the browser windows edge.

Any insight as how to accomplish this would be appreciated. And if I find the answer I am looking for, I will share a JS Bin example.

**Answer:** http://jsbin.com/uxomul/4/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML and CSS here seem to do what you want:-

http://jsbin.com/ifolaf/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way, but it's the first thing that popped into my mind.

```
.flex {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    left: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a nested divs container with 100% width

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
 will have 35px
<div>
</div>

.container{
width: 100%;
padding: 35px;
}

.container .content{
width: 100%;
}
```